# Understanding execution of properties in Javascript funciton

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

i am starting to learn javascript and i got confused on the execution of the properties in the javascript function.

suppose i have a funciton like this

```
function Counter() {
  this.num = 0;
this.timer = console.log('hey');
};
```

now in this function, i have num and timer as a properties of the function Counter. when i try to make a instance of the function Constructor the timer property gets executed 
[image]

but when i try to call the timer property explicitly, i am not getting the value / the property is not getting executed.

[image]

what is the reason behind it?

Comment: Please use correct capitalization. We use it for a reason: It helps the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> now in this function, i have num and timer as a properties of the function Counter.

No, you have `num` and `timer` properties of objects *created by* calling `Counter` as a constructor (via `new`, or `Reflect.construct`, etc.).

> but when i try to call the timer property explicitly, i am not getting the value / the property is not getting executed

Just briefly on terminology (since this will help as you continue your learning), you don't "call" properties, and properties are not "executed." You "get" their value, or "access" them, or "read" them. (Or, when they're on the left-hand side of an assignment, you "set" them or "assign to" them or "write to" them.)

Your code is successfully getting the value of the `timer` property, which is the value that `console.log('hey')` returned, which is `undefined`.

If you meant for doing something with `timer` to make it run the `console.log`, you'd want to put it in a function:

```
this.timer = function() {
    console.log('hey');
};
```

and then call it (because you do "call" functions):

```
d.timer();
```

---

Side note:

**If** that's what you meant to do, while it's perfectly fine to create functions within the constructor like that, it's slightly more common to assign them to the prototype object that `new Counter` will give to the objects it creates. With ES5 and earlier, you'd do that like this:

```
function Counter() {
    this.num = 0;
} // <== No ; here, it's a declaration, not a statement

Counter.prototype.timer = function() {
    console.log('hey');
};
```

In ES2015+, you'd probably use `class` syntax instead:

```
class Counter() {
    constructor() {
        this.num = 0;
    }

    timer() {
        console.log('hey');
    };
}
```

You use them the same way (via `new`).

Comment: well, but why am i getting the console printed when i just create an object of the Counter function? i am not accessing the property i have just created the object then why is the console getting printed?

Comment: @LijinDurairaj - The code in `Counter` runs the `console.log` and assigns its result (`undefined`) to `this.timer`. So naturally, `new Counter` (which runs the code in `Counter`) shows `hey` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy.

`this.timer = console.log('hey');`

This line assigns to the property `timer` the return value of `console.log('hey')`.

`console.log` prints in the console, but does not return anything, so your property stays `undefined`.

You are confused because you mix what is printed in the console and the actual return value.

If you just run in the console the following: `console.log('hey')`, you will see the following: `hey` then `undefined`. What the `console.log` function prints, then its return value.

Answer (score 0):

On creating a new object using `Counter` as a constructor, a new object is created with 2 properties i.e. `num` and `timer`. `num` is initialized to `0` while `timer` is initialized with the return value of `console.log()` function which is `undefined`. This return value is stored as value of timer property and each time you get this while reading it.

If I understand correctly, you wants to add some functionality to the `timer` property as a function, you can do it by adding this to the prototype property of `Counter` so that all objects created using a constructor can inherit it.

```js
function Counter() {
  this.num = 0;
};

Counter.prototype.timer = function() {
  this.timer = console.log('hey');
}

let obj = new Counter();

obj.timer();
```